# How to save new line from android?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am saving data from edit textbox and getting that to save into pdf....It works fine but if i write text into multiline....it takes as single line...and make pdf file with single line...so how can i get the new line to save into pdf??? Here is code which send data for save data...

```
Intent i = new Intent(AddText.this,GetText.class);
i.putExtra("data",editText.getText().toString());
startActivity(i);
```

And in next page i am getting data....

```
String data = getIntent().getExtras().getString("data");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(AddText.this,GetText.class);
i.putExtra("data",(editText.getText().toString()).replaceAll("\\n", "\n"));
startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

use `\n` whereever you want to use new line. in your code.

for suppose if you want to save pdf with name `Android\npdf` then you must type like this only and you can get string

Comment: ok....but i am writing content to edit textbox with multline...that i am getting into data...and that data i am saving into pdf file...so now where i have to use `\n`